# Javacv: Decoding H.264 "live" stream coming from red5 server on android device

Tags: android, ffmpeg, red5, javacv, live-streaming

Here is my problem,
I have implemented a server side application using Red5, which sends H.264 encoded live stream, on client side the stream is received as byte[]
In order to decode it on Android client side i have followed the **Javacv-FFmpeg** library. The code for decoding is as follows

```
public Frame decodeVideo(byte[] data,long timestamp){
           frame.image = null;
           frame.samples = null;
           avcodec.av_init_packet(pkt);
           BytePointer video_data = new BytePointer(data);
           avcodec.AVCodec codec = avcodec.avcodec_find_decoder(codec_id);
           video_c = null;
           video_c = avcodec.avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
           video_c.width(320);
           video_c.height(240);
           video_c.pix_fmt(0);
           video_c.flags2(video_c.flags2()|avcodec.CODEC_FLAG2_CHUNKS);
           avcodec.avcodec_open2(video_c, codec, null))
           picture = avcodec.avcodec_alloc_frame()
           pkt.data(video_data);
           pkt.size(data.length);
           int len = avcodec.avcodec_decode_video2(video_c, picture, got_frame, pkt);
           if ((len >= 0) && ( got_frame[0] != 0)) {
             ....
              process the decoded frame into **IPLImage of Javacv** and render it with **Imageview** of Android
           }
}
```

Data received from server is as follows
Few Frames having following pattern
**17 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 09 10 00 00 00 0F 06 00 01 C0 01 07 09 08 04 9A 00 00 03 00 80 00 00 16 EF 65 88 80 07 00 05 6C 98 90 00**...

Many frames having following pattern
**27 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 09 30 00 00 00 0C 06 01 07 09 08 05 9A 00 00 03 00 80 00 00 0D 77 41 9A 02 04 15 B5 06 20 E3 11 E2 3C 46** ....

With H.264 codec for decoder, decoder outputs length >0 but got_frames=0 always.
With MPEG1 codec, decoder outputs length >0 and got_frames>0 but the output image is green or distorted.

However following FFmpegFrameGrabber code of javacv i can decode the local files( H.264 encoded ) with similar code as above.

I wonder what details i am missing, and header related data manipulation or setting codec appropriate for decoder.

Any suggestion, help appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Atlast... finally got to working after lots of RnD.
What i am missing is alalyze the video frame structure. Video is made up of "I" , "P" frames.. "I" frame is information frame, which stores the information about next subsequent frames. "P" frame is picture frame, which holds actual video frame...
So i need to decode the "P" frames w.r.t information in "I" frame..
So the final code is something as follows

```
public IplImage decodeFromVideo(byte[] data, long timeStamp) {
avcodec.av_init_packet(reveivedVideoPacket); // Empty AVPacket
/*
 * Determine if the frame is a Data Frame or Key. IFrame 1 = PFrame 0 = Key
 * Frame
 */
byte frameFlag = data[1];
byte[] subData = Arrays.copyOfRange(data, 5, data.length);

BytePointer videoData = new BytePointer(subData);
if (frameFlag == 0) {
    avcodec.AVCodec codec = avcodec
            .avcodec_find_decoder(avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
    if (codec != null) {
        videoCodecContext = null;
        videoCodecContext = avcodec.avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
        videoCodecContext.width(320);
        videoCodecContext.height(240);
        videoCodecContext.pix_fmt(avutil.AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P);
        videoCodecContext.codec_type(avutil.AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);
        videoCodecContext.extradata(videoData);
        videoCodecContext.extradata_size(videoData.capacity());

        videoCodecContext.flags2(videoCodecContext.flags2()
                | avcodec.CODEC_FLAG2_CHUNKS);
        avcodec.avcodec_open2(videoCodecContext, codec,
                (PointerPointer) null);

        if ((videoCodecContext.time_base().num() > 1000)
                && (videoCodecContext.time_base().den() == 1)) {
            videoCodecContext.time_base().den(1000);
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("test", "Codec could not be opened");
    }
}

if ((decodedPicture = avcodec.avcodec_alloc_frame()) != null) {
    if ((processedPicture = avcodec.avcodec_alloc_frame()) != null) {
        int width = getImageWidth() > 0 ? getImageWidth()
                : videoCodecContext.width();
        int height = getImageHeight() > 0 ? getImageHeight()
                : videoCodecContext.height();

        switch (imageMode) {
        case COLOR:
        case GRAY:
            int fmt = 3;
            int size = avcodec.avpicture_get_size(fmt, width, height);
            processPictureBuffer = new BytePointer(
                    avutil.av_malloc(size));
            avcodec.avpicture_fill(new AVPicture(processedPicture),
                    processPictureBuffer, fmt, width, height);
            returnImageFrame = opencv_core.IplImage.createHeader(320,
                    240, 8, 1);
            break;
        case RAW:
            processPictureBuffer = null;
            returnImageFrame = opencv_core.IplImage.createHeader(320,
                    240, 8, 1);
            break;
        default:
            Log.d("showit",
                    "At default of swith case 1.$SwitchMap$com$googlecode$javacv$FrameGrabber$ImageMode[ imageMode.ordinal()]");
        }

        reveivedVideoPacket.data(videoData);
        reveivedVideoPacket.size(videoData.capacity());

        reveivedVideoPacket.pts(timeStamp);
        videoCodecContext.pix_fmt(avutil.AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P);
        decodedFrameLength = avcodec.avcodec_decode_video2(videoCodecContext,
                decodedPicture, isVideoDecoded, reveivedVideoPacket);

if ((decodedFrameLength >= 0) && (isVideoDecoded[0] != 0)) {
 .... Process image same as javacv .....
}
```

Hope it wil help others..

Comment: I think that is the answer to my problem, but I didn't understand this :I

Comment: Hi @Ichigo Kurosaki, would it work same for exact same functionality on JavaSE? how would the code look? do you have an idea, please?